# How does changing DAY_OF_WEEK in java.util.Calendar work?

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to change DayofWeek in Calendar but doesnt appear to be working as I expect. Here is an example. I set calendar time to a Friday time, but when I set Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK to Calendar.SUNDAY, it is moving forward to next week. Since Calendar.SUNDAY is first day of week by default, shouldn't it move the time back to beginning of current week?

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class GenericWeekdayOpenFunction implements TimePeriodFunction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Nov 8 is Friday
        long time = DateUtilities.newDateTimeAsMillis(2013, 11, 8, 10, 00, 00);
        System.out.println(DateUtilities.formatGmtDatetime(time));

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(time);

        // move day of week to Sunday, expect date to be Nov 3
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        System.out.println(DateUtilities.formatGmtDatetime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));    // wrong

        // move day of week to Friday, expect date to be Nov 8
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
        System.out.println(DateUtilities.formatGmtDatetime(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
08-11-2013 10:00:00.000
10-11-2013 10:00:00.000
08-11-2013 10:00:00.000
```

Comment: Also, realized changing to any other day of week works. Only "Sunday" fails.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario working fine with basic `Calendar` class usage:

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date d = new Date(113, 10, 8, 10, 0, 0);
c.setTimeInMillis(d.getTime());
System.out.println(c.getTime());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.FRIDAY);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Output:

> Fri Nov 08 10:00:00 IST 2013
>
> Sun Nov 03 10:00:00 IST 2013
>
> Fri Nov 08 10:00:00 IST 2013

Note that `Date(113, 10, 8, 10, 0, 0);` is used only for quick check, it is deprecated though. Trying for any other combination also works fine. Can you just try using basic `Calendar` API and print dates ie

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(c.getTime());//current day
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

second date should go back to previous sunday not upcoming one. If it's working for you then  `DateUtilities` implementation may be doubtful.

Comment: if I use the above code, it still prints the same result (different from yours), so something might be different with the calendar class. What is your JVM version? I am just using raw epoch value now (1383904800000) corresponding to 2013/11/08 10:00:00 GMT

Comment: my version is 1.6.0_43. Running the exact same code as above generates different result (moving Sunday forward by a week)

Answer (score -1):

I think that the method `set(int field, int value)`
Works approaching to the nearest day (not to the DAY_OF_WEEK of the same week).
But you can use the function `add(int field, int amount)` in this case `add(Calendar.DATE, -5)` to do that.

Comment: In real scenario, I dont know the day of week of current time, but I need to retrieve a window containing the beginning and end days of current week.

Comment: Then use:
`if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) { cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -6)}`